# SonarLint Plugin Initialisation Error in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I have recently installed SonarLint plugin in Eclipse IDE on one of my workstation.

However, while initialising the plugin, I am getting an error

> Illegal character in path at index 16

because of which the plugin is not working as it fails while initialisation only.

I have used SonarLint frequently on other desktops as well, but I have never encountered such issue before.

**Note:** Username has been intentionally masked in the folder path shown in the screenshot below.

[image: SonarLint Plugin - Initialisation Error]

Error stack trace:

```
Unable to load plugin bundleentry://945.fwk697742350/plugins/sonar-html-plugin-3.6.0.3106.jar
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/eclipse/../../Users/ABC/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.17.0_1709980481_win32_win32_x86_64/plugins/org.sonarlint.eclipse.core_7.2.1.42550/plugins/sonar-html-plugin-3.6.0.3106.jar
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2913) at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3084) 
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3166) 
at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3114) 
at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:600) 
at java.base/java.net.URL.TOURI(URL.java:1061) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.topath(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:96) 
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) 
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) 
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) 
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) 
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) 
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.getOrCreateEngine(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:64) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacadewithEngine(StandaloneEngine Facade.java:104) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.engine.StandaloneEngineFacade.runAnalysis(StandaloneEngineFacade.java:115) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:62) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AnalyzestandaloneProjectJob.runAnalysis(AnalyzeStandaloneProjectJob.java:1) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.run(AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.java:393) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.runAnalysisAndUpdateMarkers(AbstractAnalyzeProjectjob.java:201) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractAnalyzeProjectJob.doRun(AbstractAnalyzeProjectjob.java:157) 
at org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.AbstractsonarProjectJob.run(AbstractSonarProjectJob.java:45) 
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: Show us the full stack trace as plain text, not an image.

Comment: @greg-449 I have updated the question and added the stack trace. Please check.

Comment: Looks like they weren't prepared for dealing with paths that have spaces in them.